# ARCore android app to be installed on Non supported device

Tags: android, arcore

I have created one Android App which has AR features along with some other features. So I wanted my app to install on all devices and the AR to be worked only on supported devices.
Please help me how can I achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your app is what is called 'AR Optional' in the ARCore documentation:

> An AR Optional app uses ARCore to augment a different functionality. An AR Optional app has optional AR features, which are activated only on ARCore supported devices that have Google Play Services for AR installed.
>
> AR Optional apps can be installed and run on devices that don't support ARCore.
> When users install an AR Optional app, the Google Play Store will not automatically install Google Play Services for AR with the app.

from: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/enable-arcore (at the time of writing)

There is a a utility method available in ArCoreApk to check if the device supports ARCore and if so if it is available - ArCoreApk.checkAvailability().

It's worth being aware that some have reported inconsistent results using this check, although it does seem to work in many cases - see the discussion here for example: https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/162